# How to get type of parent by jquery

Tags: jquery, parent

If a user clicks on a button (class as button), then what is the way to know the type of parent element by jquery?
Lets look at layout:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Menu</td></tr>
<tr><td>Submenu of the page</td><td>
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="fullname" value="" />
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
</form>

<table>
   <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Password</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead>
   <tbody>
          <tr><td>Mr.X</td><td>1234</td><td><input type="button" class="button" value="check" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Mr.Y</td><td>1234</td><td><input type="button" class="button" value="check" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Mr.Z</td><td>4567</td><td><input type="button" class="button" value="check" /></td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<div>
this is some text and the below button check whether it is div<br />
<input type="button" class="button" value="check" />
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now if a user clicks either on `Submit` button of the form or `check` button of the table, jquery code has to determine whether the parent is form or table or whatever it is. I have to take some action based on the type of parent (i.e: if type is form then serializeArray() or if type of form is table then after getting callback data, tr will be updated..etc). Here `parent' does not mean the immediate parent of the DOM, rather it means the highest part of the`.button` class.

How can I get the whether the parent is form or table or a div etc?

Comment: In click event, `$(this).parent().prop('nodeName')`

Comment: Why not place different classes on the buttons, and assign different click-event handlers accordingly?

Comment: No it is not working. It is returning `td` as the form or table is part of another `td` of table. I have updated the layout. Plz review the layout.

Comment: use `.closest()`. see my answer below.

Comment: What do you mean by "Here parent [...] means the highest part of the`.button` class"? In your example code, all the `.button` elements are ultimately inside a `<table>` element.

Comment: Why not get all the parents(include everything until body tag) of button and after that filter it out

Answer (score 2):

Your statement "Here parent [...] means the highest part of the `.button` class" is unclear. I am guessing you mean the highest ancestor element that is within the `<td>` element of the top `<table>` element. Let's call that the "container" element. Currently, you can get that element using:

```
var $container = $('body>table>tbody>tr:last>td:last');
```

(Note: It would be a lot easier if it had on `id` or a `class` on it.)

Now you can get the type of the "parent" element for the clicked button by using:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var parentType = $(this).parentsUntil($container).last().prop('nodeName');
    alert(parentType);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66vg1dmt/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).parent().prop("tagName")` to get tag name. I have created [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hardikvd/jxz8jkjr/) for this. Please check.

Comment: No it is not working. It is returning `td` as the form or table is part of another `td` of table. I have updated the layout. Plz review the layout.

Answer (score -1):

Use `closest()`:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).closest('form').length) { /* it's inside a <form> block */ }
    else { /* it's not inside a <form> block */ }
});
```

This (coupled with your current DOM) is likely bad design however. I would do something like this instead:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Menu</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Submenu of the page</td><td>
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" name="fullname" value="" />
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
            <input type="submit" class="button" data-button-type="form" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <table>
            <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Password</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Mr.X</td><td>1234</td><td><input type="button" class="button" data-button-type="table" value="check" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Mr.Y</td><td>1234</td><td><input type="button" class="button" data-button-type="table" value="check" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Mr.Z</td><td>4567</td><td><input type="button" class="button" data-button-type="table" value="check" /></td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Your JS would be:

```
$('.button[data-button-type]').on('click', function() {
    var buttonType = $(this).attr('data-button-type');
    if (buttonType === 'form') { /* Handle form buttons */ }
    else if (buttonType === 'table') { /* Handle table buttons */ }
    else if (buttonType === 'div') { /* Handle div buttons */ }
});
```

Comment: why the downvote? this is exactly what was asked in the OP

Comment: No, it is not, I don't want to limit it's scope to only table or form, it may be a paragraph or div also. So the type should be dynamic. It should return the tag name of the type.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid _"I don't limit it's scope to only table or form, it may be a paragraph or div also. So the type should be dynamic. It should return the tag name of the type. "_ Can include this detail at Question ?

Comment: you're not using terms consistently. `parent` is a specific term that means the immediate ancestor of an element. if you're trying to figure out if the clicked element is inside a form or not, this code will do that. if you have other requirements, spell them out.

Comment: Having a single function handle such different situations is likely a bad design choice anyway. Add differentiating class names or data attributes to the "buttons" that you want to act differently and have separate event handlers for those.